# Zend HashTable API: zend_hash_clean()

Tags: php, memory-leaks, hashtable, php-internals

I'm new to **Zend** engine and writing an extension. According to [this page](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/hashtables/hashtable_api.html) if I want to remove all elements from a hashtable but not actually destroy everything, then I can use the `zend_hash_clean()` function.

However, when I carefully studied this particular function, I realised that the array of buckets is not released as in `zend_hash_destroy()` even though the destructor is invoked for each bucket element and all the other values are reset *(nNumUsed, nNumOfElements, nInteralPointer, etc.)*.

I highly suspect this is the source of my memory leaks.

Please let me know if I'm wrong. Any suggestion or pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: That's quite the point of clean, to not release the Buckets and index maps and be able to reuse it… it's basically equivalent to destroy+init again. Use destroy if you want to free the memory.

Comment: But as far as I can tell, the indices have been reset (reinitialized as you said) and yet the buckets are not released. When a new value is inserted, new memory is allocated... thus memory leaks occur. Thanks!

Comment: Did you call `FREE_HASHTABLE()`?